# Chatbot client and class modification

Tags: java, chatbot

```
ChatBot Class Modification:

Modify the reply() method of the ChatBot class to recognize additional words and phrases. 

Part 1: Everyone must complete this section.

When the userInput parameter value is:     The reply method should return:
how do I quit                           enter quit
how do I exit                           enter quit
how do I stop                           enter quit
how do I ____                           do you really want to do that
how are you                             I'm fine
how ______                              I don't know

Add two additional words or phrases to recognize and respond to.

ChatBot Client Modification:

Modify the ChatBot client application to loop until the end-user enters "quit".
```

Here is my service class
/

```
**
 * Java Chatbot Service class
 * @author Blake
 * 3/5/2012
 */

/**
  * Default constructor.
  */
public class Chatbot
{
   private String name; /** Users name */
    private String introbot; /** Name of the Chatbot */
    private String reply; /** Replies to the input of the string name and string introbot */

    /**
      * Constructs mutebot object
      * @param mutebow - returns name of mutebot
      */
    public Chatbot()
        {
            name = "MuteBot";
        }


    /**
     * Changes Name
     * @param name - new name
     */
    public void setName (String n)
    {
    name = n;
    }

    /**
     * Accesses name
     * @return a brand new name
     */
    public String getName()
    {
    return name;
    }

    /**
      * Accesses introbot
      * @return name of mutebot
      */
    public String introbot()
    {
    String intro = "Hello! My name is " + name;
    return intro;

    }

    /**
      * Accesses replay(String newuserinput)
      * @return introbot reply to user input
      */
    public String getreply(String newuserinput)
    {
       String reply = "I'm just learning to talk";

        if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("What"))
            reply = "Why do you ask?"; 
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("Why") )
             reply = "Why Not";
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("How"))
             reply = "I don't know!";
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("Where") )
             reply = "Anne Arundel Community College";
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("When"))
             reply = "Tomorrow";
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("how do I quit"))
            reply = "enter quit";
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("how do I exit"))
            reply = "enter quit";
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("how do I stop"))
            reply = "enter quit";
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("how are you"))
            reply = "I'm fine";
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("how do you do"))
             reply = "I am doing well";
        else
           if (newuserinput.equalsIgnoreCase("how do I get out"))
             reply = "By going through the door";
        else
           if (newuserinput.indexOf("how do I" ) ==0)
            { String substring = newuserinput.substring(8);

            reply = "do you really want to do that" + substring;
            }
        else
           if (newuserinput.indexOf("how" ) ==0)
            { String substring = newuserinput.substring(10);


            reply = "I don't know" + substring ;
            }



        return reply;

    }
}
```

Here is my client/application class

```
/**
 * Java Chatbot Client class
 * @author Blake
 * 3/5/2012
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChatbotClient
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Chatbot t = new Chatbot();
       System.out.print("What is your name? ");
       String name = input.nextLine();

         System.out.println(t.introbot());

       System.out.print(name + "> ");
       String reply = input.nextLine();

         System.out.println(t.getName() + "> " + t.getreply(reply));
         //while (reply < quit)
         /*{
            quit++
             i = i + 1

         }*/






    }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong with this part right here

Modify the ChatBot client application to loop until the end-user enters "quit".

I am trying to create a while loop which will continue until user says quit.

Comment: Please don't start your question by pasting some source code. Ask your question first. Also, you didn't explain what's wrong. Where is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following code should work for your requirements:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChatbotClient
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       Chatbot t = new Chatbot();
       System.out.print("What is your name? ");
       String name = input.nextLine();

       System.out.println(t.introbot());

       System.out.print(name + "> ");
       String reply = input.nextLine();

      while (!reply.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
        System.out.println(t.getName() + "> " + t.getreply(reply));
        System.out.print(name + "> ");
        reply = input.nextLine();
      }
     }
}
```